# HDPARM Security Erase issue

Tags: linux, ssd, wipe, hdparm

I have bought a used Agility 3 SSD. And I wanted to wipe out data from my Linux box using hdparm. But it was not OK.

Here are the steps I followed:

```
# hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass 1 /dev/sdc
security_password="1"

/dev/sdc:
 Issuing SECURITY_SET_PASS command, password="1", user=user, mode=high

# hdparm -I /dev/sdc

Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
            supported
            enabled
    not     locked
    not     frozen
    not     expired: security count
    not     supported: enhanced erase
    Security level high
    2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 
    Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5e83a97df0954cc5
       NAA             : 5
       IEEE OUI        : e83a97
       Unique ID       : df0954cc5
    Checksum: correct
```

Which, if I am not mistaken, means that the drive is ready for data wipe. **But:**

```
# hdparm --user-master u --security-erase 1 /dev/sdc
security_password="1"

/dev/sdc:
 Issuing SECURITY_ERASE command, password="1", user=user
 SECURITY_ERASE: Input/output error
```

And after that, all I see from `hdparm -I` is the following:

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sdc
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
            supported
    not     enabled
    not     locked
    not     frozen
    not     expired: security count
    not     supported: enhanced erase
    2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 
    Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5e83a97df0954cc5
       NAA             : 5
       IEEE OUI        : e83a97
       Unique ID       : df0954cc5
    Checksum: correct
```

So, I suppose that I did not manage to wipe data. Is that correct? If so, what information would you need in order to help me and wipe data from the SSD?

Comment: How is your SSD conntected to the PC/Laptop? Because: "Warning: Do not proceed with this if your drive isn't connected directly to a SATA interface. Issuing the Secure Erase command on a drive connected via USB or a SAS/RAID card could potentially brick the drive!". [Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSD_Memory_Cell_Clearing). Also Try maybe a longer password, just to make sure.

Comment: Yes, of course is directly connected (and not mounted :) ). I also tried the instructions of https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase. Of course that did not solved the issue.